# Poor performance on multiple aggregations

Tags: mongodb, gtfs

I have a GTFS data as collections on mongodb. Collections look exactly as in documentation: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference

I am trying to return all of the stops with their type of transportation (tram, bus or multiple in my case). To get to that, I have to get all routes on that stop because `route` collection has a `route_type` field which is the case (value `0` - tram, value `3` - bus).

(Pseudocode)

```
Get all stops
Join stoptimes on stops.stop_id = stoptimes.stop_id
Join trips on stoptimes.trip_id = trips.trip_id
Join routes on trips.trip_id = routes.route_id
Compare routes.route_type for each stop according to documentation and return type
```

In my GTFS data, there is a rule that every tramline has one or two characters ID and busline has 3 characters ID. These ids are `route_id` field in my GTFS. So it gives me a possibility to ommit one join:

(Pseudocode):

```
Get all stops
Join stoptimes on stop_id = stoptimes.stop_id
Join trips on stoptimes.trip_id = trips.trip_id
Compare trips.route_id for each stop by length and return type
```

Below there is my query. I've added `$limit: 10` for debugging purposes. Query takes 2028 ms for 10 stops.

Collections length:

```
stops: 6724 documents,
stoptimes: 4823250 documents,
trips: 174698 documents,
routes: 350 documents
```

Questions:

- How to make it faster? For 1000 stops, it takes around 75 seconds to execute...
- When `$group`ing, I am adding `$first` expression not to loose fields which I need in the final result. Is there a better way to include them in the final result?
- I've made an `$unwind: '$lines'` twice because the query made a nested array. How to avoid it?

  ```
  Stop.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      'stop_id': {
        $regex: /^\d{6}$/
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "stoptimes",
      localField: "stop_id",
      foreignField: "stop_id",
      as: "stoptimes"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "trips",
      localField: "stoptimes.trip_id",
      foreignField: "trip_id",
      as: "trips"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$stop_id',
      stop_name: {
        $first: '$stop_name'
      },
      stop_lat: {
        $first: '$stop_lat'
      },
      stop_lon: {
        $first: '$stop_lon'
      },
      lines: {
        $addToSet: "$trips.route_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$lines'
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$lines'
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      stop_name: 1,
      stop_lat: 1,
      stop_lon: 1,
      lines: {
        $strLenCP: "$lines"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        stop_id: '$_id',
        stop_name: '$stop_name',
        stop_lat: '$stop_lat',
        stop_lon: '$stop_lon',
        line: '$lines'
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      stop_id: '$_id.stop_id',
      stop_name: '$_id.stop_name',
      stop_lat: '$_id.stop_lat',
      stop_lon: '$_id.stop_lon',
      line: '$_id.line'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$stop_id',
      stop_name: {
        $first: '$stop_name'
      },
      stop_lat: {
        $first: '$stop_lat'
      },
      stop_lon: {
        $first: '$stop_lon'
      },
      lineNameLengths: {
        $addToSet: '$line'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      stop_id: '$_id',
      stop_name: '$stop_name',
      stop_lat: '$stop_lat',
      stop_lon: '$stop_lon',
      type: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [{
              case: {
                $gte: [{
                  $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                }, 3]
              },
              then: "multiple"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [{
                    $eq: [{
                      $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                    }, 2]
                  },
                  {
                    $not: [{
                      $in: [3, '$lineNameLengths']
                    }]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "tram"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [{
                    $eq: [{
                      $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                    }, 2]
                  },
                  {
                    $in: [3, '$lineNameLengths']
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "multiple"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [{
                    $eq: [{
                      $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                    }, 1]
                  },
                  {
                    $in: [1, '$lineNameLengths']
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "tram"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [{
                    $eq: [{
                      $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                    }, 1]
                  },
                  {
                    $in: [2, '$lineNameLengths']
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "tram"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [{
                    $eq: [{
                      $size: "$lineNameLengths"
                    }, 1]
                  },
                  {
                    $in: [3, '$lineNameLengths']
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: "bus"
            }
          ],
          default: ""
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
  ```

Is it possible to make this query execute much faster?

This is my first mongodb project, so hopefully I might made some stupid mistakes, easy to correct with more experienced collegues.

Comment: Stupid mistake 1. Remove all the "joins". If you have a design relying on that many relational joins, then you're using the wrong database. Use an RDBMS instead. MongoDB was not designed for this. Otherwise, accept you are using MongoDB and you actually chose it for an informed reason, and then instead start embedding all the "related" data where it actually makes sense to do so. If you did not understand that difference, then you most definitely chose the wrong database.

Comment: Bottom line is "multiple `$lookup`" statements and multiple `$unwind` statements are  really bad for performance. Worse yet is that you have created a "cartesian product" you are not even aware of by unwinding an array and then unwinding another array on top of that. Essentially each "unwound" element is now repeated  by the number of unwound elements in the other array. Huge problems with the implementation here and not actually solvable without a specific and "minimal" problem presentation and more than a modicum of openness to changing your implemented schema and storage.